# Having difficulty with Dependency properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I created my own `CustomSlider` (`UserControl`). See the code below:

**Code behind:**

```
    public partial class CustomSlider : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public CustomSlider()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += CustomSlider_Loaded;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty;

        static CustomSlider()
        {
            PositionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Position", typeof(double), typeof(CustomSlider), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());
        }

        public double Position
        {
            get
            {
                return (double)GetValue(PositionProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(PositionProperty, value);
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Position");
            }
        }

        double length = 0;

        void CustomSlider_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            track.DataContext = this;
        }

        public double MaxValue { get; set; }

        public event EventHandler ValueChangedManually;

        //Changing the position manually
        private void Border_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            length = this.Width;
            if (Double.IsNaN(this.Width))
                length = this.ActualWidth;
            Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
            try
            {
                //Position = p.X; // this didn't work too
                this.SetValue(PositionProperty, p.X);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //test
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="White" BorderBrush="Blue" MouseLeftButtonDown="Border_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
        <Label Name="track" Background="#FF4250D8" Width="{Binding Path=Position, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MouseLeftButtonDown="Border_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
    </Grid>
```

I created a new instance of my control in my form and tried to change the `Position`(one of the properties of my control) by clicking on top of `CustomSlider`. It changes the position as I expect. Then I tried to do this with `DoubleAnimation`. It works fine too. Problem is I can't change the `Position` by clicking on top of `CustomSlider` after changing the `Position` with `DoubleAnimation`. Here is the Animation code:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation();
            anim.From = 0;
            anim.To =350;
            anim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            slider.BeginAnimation(CustomSlider.PositionProperty, anim);
        }
```

Is there something wrong with my `DependecyProperty`? Please help to fix this problem. 
Thanks,

Comment: Just out of curiosity what does your slider do that the default one can't?

Comment: @ChrisW. I am making application which plays audio. I need to show where it is playing currently. User needs to  be able to change it manually. Default Slider does the exactly same thing, but my client wants different kind of UI for it.

Comment: Read [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx). Animation is one of the top priorities. In your handler, you set the property which is considered "local", it's two orders down from animations. So, you'd need to stop the animation before setting the property. Also, you don't need change notification in dependency properties. And lastly, to change the UI use `ControlTemplate` instead of rolling your own.

Comment: That because the Animation is still running, try setting the Animations FillBehaviour to Stop `anim.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;` this will stop the TimeLine and allow you to modifiy the Dependancyproperty after the animation runs

Comment: @Dilshod so why not just edit the Control template to make it look however you want instead of re-creating the whole thing? Example: http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/customize-a-slider-in-wpf-step-by-step-tutorial/

Comment: @sa_ddam213 - `FillBehavior.Stop` will stop the animation and might revert the property to its pre-animated state.

Comment: @Dilshod WPF is designed to allow you to re-style the controls to look however you want without losing their functionality. You most likely do not need to implement this.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Thanks for the tip. Stopping the animation fixed the problem. And Thanks for everyone to helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy of the `@sa_ddam213`'s comments. That solved my problem.

That because the Animation is still running, try setting the Animations FillBehaviour to Stop anim.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop; this will stop the TimeLine and allow you to modifiy the Dependancyproperty after the animation runs

FillBehavior.Stop will stop the animation and might revert the property to its pre-animated state.